# Calendar Component for n months Interval Swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, notifications, calendar, nscalendar

I'm trying to create a `UNNotificationRequest` using `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` for a quarter(every 3 months) year interval.

I've been able to create a monthly trigger

```
 let component = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second, .day], from: Date())
 let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: component, repeats: true)
```

I'm avoiding `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` cause of the 28/29/30/31 days mnemonic.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DuncanC I’m trying to create a ‘UNCalenderNotificationTrigger’ for 3 months interval.

Comment: You still haven't asked a proper question. To get a future date why not use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293453-date?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the first line is the question. And let me give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this does gives a future date but the component doesn't match `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger  dateMatching` the second time, hence the local notification doesn't repeat.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can you help please!